# What's the `IMAGE` type in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

By chance (mixing up the order of parameters), I set the column type to `IMAGE` in my postgres instance) and it worked (didn't get an error)! I have no idea what this type is, and it is not listed in [the official table of types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE).

```
mydb=# CREATE TABLE tmp_image( image_column image );
CREATE TABLE
mydb=# \d tmp_image 
               Table "public.tmp_image"
    Column    | Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------
 image_column | image |           |          |
```

Searching a bit, I found [a postgres extension called `pg_image`](http://%20https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_image/0.3.0/), but I don't have any extensions installed:

```
 \dx
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
```

I seem to be running 10.7 (`psql (PostgreSQL) 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)`).

Comment: Do you have a table named `image`?

Comment: Maybe a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/domains.html)? You can check with `\dD`

Comment: @stickybit Yes, there is a view called Image. How does that relate to types?

Comment: A table or view is also a type.

Comment: Weird, but OK :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rowtypes.html) (by accident?). From the docs:

> Whenever you create a table, a composite type is also automatically created, with the same name as the table, to represent the table's row type.

The same thing seems to apply to views even though I couldn't find this stated explicitely. Anyway check this out:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE test (id int, data text);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# CREATE TABLE test2 (id int, field test); -- note the type of [field]
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# INSERT INTO test2 (id, field) VALUES (2, ROW(1, 'test'));
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# SELECT * FROM test2;
 id | field 
----+-------
  2 | (1,test)
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT (field).data FROM test2;
 data 
------
 test
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM test;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

Note how `test` becomes a part of `test2`. It **is not** a foreign reference.